# How to add wait time between threads , If we try to run testNG classes in parallel

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, testng

I have a testNG XML file in which i want to run my test classes in parallel with thread count = 4. But I want to add some wait time between this threads, So that 4 instance of browser doesn't open at the same time. Need wait time between all instance. Is there any way to do that?.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="2" parallel="classes">
<test name="Invoice and Expenses">
<classes>
<class name="test one" />
<class name="test two" />
<class name="test three" />
<class name="test four" /> 
</classes>
</test>
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding `add some wait time between this threads` defeat the purpose of **parallelism**?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `Thread.sleep()`?

You can put it in your `@BeforeClass` method, so that it is executed before every class. Additionally, if you want separate delays for different classes, you can do something like:

```
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void justDelay() throws InterruptedException 
      {

        if(this.getClass().getName().equals("test one"))
         {
           Thread.sleep(delay1);
         }


        else if(this.getClass().getName().equals("test two"))
         {
               Thread.sleep(delay2);
         }

        else
         {
               Thread.sleep(defaultdelay)
         }

        }
```

Comment: How does it help when he will open 4 instance of browser ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. Do you mean to say I should write all the 4 classes because that's the number of them in question?

Comment: No. Assume I have 10 classes which I want to run in an order as OP stated. I will have to declare every class with if condition which obviously would be worst/extreme condition. Try to give generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 4 classes to open the browser at the same time, you may don't want them to run in parallel either, then you need to run them in sequence.

Even you added some random sleep before each each test classes, since they are still running in parallel, you can not avoid them to open the browser at the same time after it's started.

If you do want 4 classes to run in parallel, I guess the browser is only needed at some moments in your test classes rather than always needed through the tests. In this case, it's a resource contention issue in your test code. You need to manage the synchronized lock on the resource (e.g. WebDriver) where opening the browser is needed by 4 classes, so that the class asking for the browser needs to wait for the other test class to release it (closing it) before it can continue, while others are blocked waiting for the release too.